# Data are placed on the wrong dates on xAxis -nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, lineplusbarchart

I have created a linelusBarChart with nvd3. The data for the graph  is a timeseries (for both lines and bars) received from REST services. 
The problem I am facing concerns the placement of data on xAxis. When I zoom out of the graph, data are not placed on their proper positions (result shown in picture below):
[image]
But when I zoom in, data are placed on different dates than the proper ones (view image below):
[image]
How can I solve this issue?

My code is:

```
chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
                    .focusEnable(true) //gia na exei to focus Chart (range slider)     
                    .margin({ top: 50, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 80 })
                    .color(["rgb(226, 144, 36)", "rgb(66, 30, 109)", "rgb(58, 112, 150)"]);
                    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d * 1000))
                }).showMaxMin(true);

                chart.y1Axis.axisLabel("Sentiment Value");

                chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(function (d) { return d3.format(',f')(d) });
                   chart.bars.forceY([0]).padData(false); 
                chart.lines.forceY([0]).padData(false);

                chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(function (d) {
                    return d3.time.format('%d/%m/%Y')(new Date(d * 1000))
                }).showMaxMin(true);

                chart.showLegend(false);

                multichart_graph = d3.select('#multichart svg');
                testdata.map(function (series) {
                series.values = series.values.map(function (d) { return { x: d[0], y: d[1] } });
                return series;
                });

                multichart_graph.datum(testdata)
                    .transition()
                    .call(chart);
```

An overview of the data used is:

```
var testdata = [{
                 "key": "Orange line", "values": [[1279314000, -0.476492389], [1279400400, -0.4764799323],[1279486800, -0.4764816604],....]}, 
                {
                 "key": "Forecast line", "values": [[1516140000, -1.0070195523], [1516226400, 3.9973810749],...]},
                {
                "key": "Bars", "values": [[1516140000, 3], [1516226400, 2], [1516312800, 3],...],"bar": "true"}
]
```

Comment: why use `map` when you actually want `forEach`? without `testdata` it is very hard to look at

Comment: @rioV8 I have added a sample of the data I am receiving on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the location where you get NVD3 your code will not run.

I use

```
<script src="http://nvd3.org/assets/js/nv.d3.js"></script>
```

This is a version that is different than the github code. It does not have the `chart.x2Axis` for this chart type.

Looking at the code (github and nvd3.org) the bar chart uses the `historicalBar` model to show the bar chart. This uses the `d3.extent` of the `x` values for the domain of the xAxis (`d3.scale.linear`) of the values that are designated as `bar`. The bars are placed using the scale, but the width of the bar is `width/data[0].values.length`. The result is huge bars if you add a dummy data point at the combined domain start (2010-07). It is not possible to control the bar width by the user and the domain used by the xScale.

The only solution is to write the chart yourself.